# zimlet perform mail search and show result - conversation in a new tab

Tags: zimbra

How could I perfom mail search (maybe using ZmMailApp.mailSearch) in zimlet. Searching would be subject and result - conversation I would like to open in a new tab. Any idea? Or any idea where I could find some useful documentation or tutorials?

Comment: This is a very general question. Consider posting any relevant code that you have already, and ask specific questions regarding the code. See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on asking a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check [the zimlet developers guide](https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Zimlet_Developers_Guide:Introduction)? That's a pretty good documentation source for developing zimlets. Also, there's a link to the **Javascript API documentation**, where you can find further information.

About your search question: I would suggest creation a SoapDocument for a "SearchRequest" and send that using the SendRequest method. Check the above documentation for further information.